# how to check the existence of existing data in mongodb with flutter?

Tags: mongodb, flutter

I want to make a query validation for insert data. so, it can't be inserted twice or duplicated data. this is the best I got:

```dart
static Future<void> insertData(UserModel data) async {
    final existingUser = await MongoConnection.instance.userCollect.findOne(
      where.eq('userId', data.userId),
    );

    if (existingUser != null) {
      //if the userId duplicated it will return this error message.
      throw Exception("User with the same userId already exists");
    } else {
      // inserted query code
      await MongoConnection.instance.userCollect.insertOne(data.toJson());
    }
  }
```

I don't know why this query still let the data inserted.
what I miss?

thanks.